# Tkinter Text Widget Search method

Tags: python, tkinter

Where can I find the documentation of this method?

I found only this
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm
*The search method allows you to search for text. You can search for an exact match (default), or use a Tcl-style regular expression (call with the regexp option set to true).*

What does "Tcl-style regular expression" mean?

I also have a question on my code: why `self._testo.tag_add("search", pos, "%s + %sc" (pos, countVar.get()))` returns `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
Thanks in advance

```
def _trova(self):
    t1 = tkinter.Toplevel(self._finestra)
    def t():
        s = e.get()

        start = "1.0"
        while True:
            countVar = tkinter.StringVar()
            pos = self._testo.search(s, start, stopindex="end",count=countVar)
            if not pos:
                break
            self._testo.tag_config("search", background="yellow")
            self._testo.tag_add("search", pos, "%s + %sc" (pos, countVar.get()))
            start = pos + "+1c"

    e= tkinter.Entry(t1).grid(row=0, column=1)
    ok = tkinter.Button(t1, text="OK", command= t).grid(row=0, column=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I find the documentation of this method?

The canonical documentation is in the tcl/tk documentation here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M120 It assumes you are writing in tcl rather than python, but it's fairly simple to translate it into python. The python docs give a good introduction to how to do that. See [Mapping basic tk into tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#mapping-basic-tk-into-tkinter)

> What does "Tcl-style regular expression" mean?

Tkinter is a thin wrapper around a tcl interpreter. Tcl's regular expression syntax is subtly different than Python's. By "tcl-style regular expression", it means that it follows the regular expression syntax described in the [re_syntax](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) man page of the tcl project.

> I also have a question on my code: why self._testo.tag_add("search", pos, "%s + %sc" (pos, countVar.get())) returns TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

You get the error because you are trying to call a string as if it were a function (in essence, you are doing `"foo"()`. This is the offending section of code:

```
"%s + %sc" (pos, countVar.get())
```

You seem to have left out a `%` between `"%s + %sc"` and `(pos, countVar.get())`.